# adding meta data using plugin to top of head

Tags: plugins, headers, wp-head, custom-header

It seems if you use the wp_head hook as an action to put your custom metadata into the head tags of your page, it is dependent on where the theme you are using calls the wp_head. In my case, it is at the end of the head tags.

How can I force my meta data near the top of the head tags? I have a header.php file I'm calling in using a self-made plugin. I know how to write the function code to call the header.php. I just need to know how to hook it to the start of the head tags.

Thanks,
Derek

Comment: By the way, Yoast's Wordpress SEO plugin puts social stuff at the top of the head tag area. If he managed to do, I'd like to as well. Thanks!

Comment: Then search inside the plugin code, how he adds it.

Comment: his plugin is dozens of files, and I don't even know what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here's the answer:

```
function CustomHead() {
include('headcontent.php');
}
add_action('wp_head','CustomHead',1,1);
```

The key is that first "1", which sets the priority of it to run at the highest (this is an optional element, defaulting to 10, putting it at the end of the head by default). More info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

Answer (score 1):

You can [**create a custom action hook**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) into `header.php` file. Then you can use that action hook instead of `wp_head` in your plugins.

**Here's how you can create a custom action hook into wordpress.**

```
<?php do_action('wpse65597_do_meta'); ?>
```

**This is how you can hook your function into that action-hook -**

```
add_action('wpse65597_do_meta','YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME');
function YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME(){  
    // echo meta tags here  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my goal is to not edit the theme's header.php, as I'd have to re-encode it with every update. That's in fact why I'm working on my custom/personal functionality plugin.

Comment: then there'll be only action hook you can use is `wp_head`